# SQL Server 2012 - No information stores if I use INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple database and I want to prohibit inserting RegionCode if the code is not in boundary I specified (not in 1..199 and not in 701..799). Here is T-SQL query:

```
USE master
GO



-- Drop the database if it already exists
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT name 
        FROM sys.databases 
        WHERE name = 'MichaelUskov'
)
DROP DATABASE MichaelUskov
GO

CREATE DATABASE MichaelUskov
GO

USE MichaelUskov
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Regions', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE MichaelUskov.Regions


CREATE TABLE Regions
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    RegionName nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
)


IF OBJECT_ID(N'RegionCodes', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE MichaelUskov.RegionCodes


CREATE TABLE RegionCodes
(
    Code int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Region int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Regions(ID)
)
GO



IF OBJECT_ID(N'Cars', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE MichaelUskov.Cars


CREATE TABLE Cars
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Manufacturer nvarchar(20),
    Color nvarchar(20),
    GosID nvarchar(20),
    RegionCode int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RegionCodes(Code),
    LastName nvarchar(20)
)
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE Name = 'CheckValidRegionCode' AND type = 'TR') 
    DROP TRIGGER CheckVaidRegionCode
GO


CREATE TRIGGER CheckValidRegionCode 
    ON RegionCodes 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @numofwrong int
BEGIN
    SET @numofwrong = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM inserted
                      WHERE NOT(1<Code AND Code<199 OR 700<Code AND Code<799))
    if (@numofwrong != 0) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(N'Неверный формат кода региона', 10, 1)
        ROLLBACK
    END
END
GO


INSERT INTO Regions VALUES(N'Москва')
INSERT INTO Regions VALUES(N'Санкт-Петербург')
INSERT INTO Regions VALUES(N'Свердловская область')
GO

INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(77, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(97, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(177, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(197, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(777, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(78, 2)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(98, 2)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(178, 2)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(66, 3)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(96, 3)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(196, 3)
GO

INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(999, 3)
GO

INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'Volvo', N'Черный', N'А000АА', 77, N'Иванов')
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'Geely', N'Белый', N'А001АА', 96, N'Петров')
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'Volvo', N'Оранжевый', N'А002АА', 177, N'Сидоров')
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'ZAZ', N'Зеленый', N'А003АА', 96, N'Васильев')
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'Ford', N'Оранжевый', N'А000ТА', 196, N'Васечкин')
GO
```

`INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(999, 3)` is wrong and shouldn't be inserted. The trigger raises error on this line. But when I select all rows from RegionCodes, I see that there are no rows. What's the problem?

Comment: The `instead of` trigger needs to actually insert the data into the table.

Comment: The clue is in the name - for every row, including valid ones, `INSTEAD OF` inserting the specified data, it does something else - in your case, just rolling back an non-existent transaction

Comment: Also, as a general rule, never put ROLLBACK or COMMIT statements inside of triggers. Let the code that is executing the DML handle all the transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSTEAD OF` triggers completely replaces the operation they intercept. When creating such a trigger the operation that triggered it to execute **doesn't execute**, instead its code is executed, so the `INSERT` itself will never actually be run. To correct your code, the trigger must run the `INSERT` again after it checks the condition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckValidRegionCode 
    ON RegionCodes 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @numofwrong int
BEGIN
    SET @numofwrong = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM inserted
                      WHERE NOT(1<Code AND Code<199 OR 700<Code AND Code<799))
    IF (@numofwrong != 0) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(N'Неверный формат кода региона', 10, 1)
        ROLLBACK
    END
    INSERT INTO RegionCodes (Code, Region) SELECT Code, Region FROM inserted
END
```

Note that here the trigger completely overrides the original `INSERT`, hence after checking the condition its supposed to do, it must do the work itself afterwards.

However, for this kind of checking triggers are an overkill and inadecuate. The DB engine provides a better option for this, *check constraints*. This way the verification is performed by the engine itself and eliminates the need of the trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE RegionCodes
(
    Code int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Region int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Regions(ID) CONSTRAINT CK_RegionCodes_Code CHECK (1<Code AND Code<199 OR 700<Code AND Code<799)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query does what I need:

```
USE master
GO



-- Drop the database if it already exists
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT name 
        FROM sys.databases 
        WHERE name = 'MichaelUskov'
)
DROP DATABASE MichaelUskov
GO

CREATE DATABASE MichaelUskov
GO

USE MichaelUskov
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Regions', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE MichaelUskov.Regions


CREATE TABLE Regions
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    RegionName nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
)


IF OBJECT_ID(N'RegionCodes', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE MichaelUskov.RegionCodes


CREATE TABLE RegionCodes
(
    Code int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Region int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Regions(ID)
)
GO



IF OBJECT_ID(N'Cars', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE MichaelUskov.Cars


CREATE TABLE Cars
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Manufacturer nvarchar(20),
    Color nvarchar(20),
    GosID nvarchar(20),
    RegionCode int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RegionCodes(Code),
    LastName nvarchar(20)
)
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE Name = 'CheckValidRegionCode' AND type = 'TR') 
    DROP TRIGGER CheckVaidRegionCode
GO


CREATE TRIGGER CheckValidRegionCode 
    ON RegionCodes 
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE @numofwrong int
BEGIN
    SET @numofwrong = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM inserted
                      WHERE NOT(1<Code AND Code<199 OR 700<Code AND Code<799))
    if (@numofwrong != 0) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(N'Неверный формат кода региона', 10, 1)
        RETURN
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO RegionCodes SELECT * FROM inserted
    END
END
GO


INSERT INTO Regions VALUES(N'Москва')
INSERT INTO Regions VALUES(N'Санкт-Петербург')
INSERT INTO Regions VALUES(N'Свердловская область')
GO

INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(77, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(97, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(177, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(197, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(777, 1)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(78, 2)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(98, 2)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(178, 2)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(66, 3)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(96, 3)
INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(196, 3)
GO

INSERT INTO RegionCodes VALUES(999, 3)
GO

INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'Volvo', N'Черный', N'А000АА', 77, N'Иванов')
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'Geely', N'Белый', N'А001АА', 96, N'Петров')
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'Volvo', N'Оранжевый', N'А002АА', 177, N'Сидоров')
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'ZAZ', N'Зеленый', N'А003АА', 96, N'Васильев')
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(N'Ford', N'Оранжевый', N'А000ТА', 196, N'Васечкин')
GO
```